# How to position oneself, if one has little practical engineering background or function, but may have a broader insight into mathematical modeling?

Tags: career-development

How to position oneself, if one has little practical engineering background or function, but may have a broader insight into mathematical modeling?

Or, lets say:

> I could write models to prove properties about the thing perhaps, but I wouldn't necessarily build that
> thing.

And this is not the same as "writing some Matlab alongside work to see what I'm doing".

So how does a "software person" position oneself so that it's also viable towards "practical", w/o having the experience of a "practical engineer"?

This is also perhaps why the degree contents for mech. engr. or elec. engr. or software is different, while they're a bit of overlap. But the profiles are different.

So what's it that a "computational methods expert" looks for instead of what a mech. engr. using Matlab or similar looks for?

What I think:

- Such computational methods expert should be concerned about implementing software that aids engineering analysis. W/o necessarily being the one doing such analysis. But studying the design of such software systems.